# iOS Swift SHA1 Base64 encoding with Hash pod

Tags: ios, swift

I installed Pod 'Hash' and used `import Hash` in Swift. I have `let token = Hash(message: "message", algorithm: .sha1)` but I need the result in Base64 encoding. How can I do this? I cannot use CryptoKit because my minimum deployment target is too old.

Answer (score 1):

[I guess this is the package are using: https://github.com/rwbutler/Hash](https://github.com/rwbutler/Hash/blob/master/Hash/Classes/Message%20Digest/Hash.swift)

`let token = Hash(message: "message", algorithm: .sha1)` the Hash you are using return Hash object which has data function, and then you can get the base64 from data like this:
`let base64String = token.data().base64EncodedString()`

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is what I eventually arrived at and it seems to work.